# Grouping data in mapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a csv file which I have loaded into hadoop. Data sample is below.

```
name | shop      | balance
tom  | shop a    | -500
john | shop b    | 200
jane | shop c    | 5000
```

Results:

```
bad 1
normal 1
wealthy 1
```

I have to get the balance for each person and then put them into groups(bad(<0), normal(1 to 500), good(>500)

I'm not 100% sure how to put the groups into mapReduce. Do I put it in the reducer? or mapper?

Splitting the csv file(mapper):

```
String[] tokens = value.toString().split(",");
Sting balance = tokens[3];
```

Creating groups:

```
String[] category = new String[3];

category[0] = "Bad"
category[1] = "Normal"
category[2] = "Good"
```

I also have this if/else statement:

```
if (bal =< 500){
//put into cat 0 
} else if ( bal >= 501 && bal <=1500){
// put into cat 1
} else {
//put into cat 2
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to implement this would be:

Map:

```
map() {
    if (bal <= 0) { //or 500, or whatever
        emit (bad, 1);
    } else if (bal <= 500) { // or 1500, or whatever
        emit (normal, 1);
    } else {
        emit (good, 1);
    }
}
```

Reduce (and combiner, as well):

```
reduce(key, values) {
    int count = 0;
    while (values.hasNext()) {
       count += values.next();
    }
    emit (key, count);
}
```

It's exactly the same as [the word count example](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html#Example%3a+WordCount+v1.0), where, in your case, you have three words (categories): bad, normal, good.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but I keep getting an error: operator <= cannot be applied to java.lang.String, int. I have tried everything I can think of to fix it but nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: That's just a pseudocode with the main logic of the program. It's not compilable, for sure. Anyway, yes, this can be solved by parsing the numeric value, like: `Double.parseDouble(bal)`, but these are java-related questions and not map-reduce related.